# How do I use WYSIWGS with redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I need to use a text editor as part of my form. I am using redux-form in my project. How do I use WYSIWYGs inside my redux forms? What are the best practices to use the same?

Answer (score 0):

I use [this component](https://gist.github.com/erikras/5ca8dc618bae5dbc8faf7d2324585d01) I wrote. It requires that the import from `react-rte` be placed in `window.RichTextEditor`.